# Python - What is tkinter's default window reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, destroy

```
import tkinter.messagebox
a = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('','hi')
```

After the 'askquestion' window closes the tkinter window still remains.

I can resolve this by the following:

```
import tkinter.messagebox
top = tkinter.Tk()
a = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('','hi')
top.destroy()
```

This destroys the window.

My question is:

Is there a way to destroy the window without creating a reference to it?

I tried:

```
import tkinter.messagebox
a = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('','hi')
tkinter.Tk().destroy()
```

but that has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you destroy the root window, Tkinter try to recreate one when you call `askquestion`.

Don't destory the root window. Instead use [`withdraw`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method).

```
import tkinter.messagebox
tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
a=tkinter.messagebox.askquestion('','hi')
```